# How to convert UTC time to normal time format using Moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert UTC time formate to local time format:

Here is the example:

I got the UTC format time from the server side, which looks like:  2014-09-17T11:09:58+1100. My requirement is to convert it to 17 Sep 2014.

However, I tried all the following method, but still get 03 Sep 2014. why this happened?

what I tried:

```
function dateFormatter(UTC) {
        var dateFormat = 'd MMM YYYY';

        console.log(moment(UTC).zone('+1100').format(dateFormat));
        return moment(UTC).format(dateFormat).toLocaleString();
    }
```

Those two method still get the same result: 03 Sep 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- UTC refers to [Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which is a system of timekeeping - not a format.
- A value that is "in UTC" would have an offset of zero.  Since you said the value has an offset of `+1100`, it doesn't make any sense to call it "UTC".
- You should not call the `zone` function.  That is for converting an input value to a particular time zone offset.  Since your input value already contains an offset, calling it makes little sense.
- If you're just trying to preserve the offset that you were given, then use [`moment.parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) instead.
- The [format string characters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) are case sensitive.  Lower-case `d` is for the day of the week as a number 0 through 6.  You should use an upper-case `D` to specify the day of the month.
- `toLocaleString` is not required.  Note that you were calling that function from a string, not a date or a moment.

Putting it all together:

```
function dateFormatter(s) {
    return moment.parseZone(s).format('D MMM YYYY');
}
```

Comment: +1 also probably worth mentioning the [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) while clarifying UTC.